# What is this present we received from our hotel in China?

Tags: china, identify-this, beijing

On our trip to China, we received this thing next to the pen in the figure as a gift both in Hangzhou and Beijing. The pen serves only for comparison of size.

It is made of metal and not flexible. Written on the back of the pendant is the name of the hotel in Chinese characters.

Can someone tell me what it is and what it is used for? I forgot to ask in the hotel.

[image: What is this thing?]

[image: Something written on the back]

Comment: If almost sharp, a letter opener, if not sharp I would say a book mark.

Comment: It's not sharp, at least not sharp enough to cut anything. Though it seems to be too thick for a book mark. Stirring would certainly be possible. The bend metal would allow to put it into a glass or something. Are Chinese into cocktails?

Comment: Same Chinese ideograms on the back of both?

Comment: @mkennedy The pictures show both sides of the pendant. The metal "hook" is just plain as shown in the upper picture.

Comment: I googled Metal Bookmark, and selected Images and found several much like this. I am not going to put it in an answer as this is not a travel question and should/might get closed or deleted.

Comment: I'm (regrettably) voting to close this question as off-topic because sometimes wonderful questions about Chinese bookmarks are not travel questions.

Comment: You mentioned that you saw or received them in Beijing and Hangzhou. I was wondering if the characters on the back were the same--then possibly a saying like "good travels" or "sleep well" or different, which could still be different sayings or possibly the hotel names.

Comment: Willeke is correct - this is a traditional Chinese bookmark.